# being able to pick a number and display the value of that number

Tags: python

am creating a turn based game i want to be able to have user1 pick a number and whatever that number corresponds to should print out what it is and then user2 should be able to do that again and break when 2 cards been picked

```
import random

class Pokemon():
    def __init__(self,name,stage,atk_type,hp):
        self.name = name
        self.stage = stage
        self.atk_type = atk_type
        self.hp = hp

    def __str__(self):
                return(f"name: {self.name}\nstage: {self.stage}\natk_type: {self.atk_type}\nhp: {self.hp}\n")


def menu():

    print("Pick Your Pokemon:\n 1. Squirtle\n 2. Charizard\n 3. Exit")
    choice = input("Pick Your Pokemon! : ")
    
    Charizard = Pokemon("Charizard", "Stage 2 ", ["atk_type - Fire", "Attacks - Flamethrower, Ember, Fire Blast , Damage 12"], 120)
    print(Charizard)
    Squirtle = Pokemon("Squirtle", "Basic", ["atk_type - Water", "Attacks - Bubble, Tackle, Water Pulse, AQUA Jet, Damage 3"], 60)
    print(Squirtle)
    Charmander = Pokemon("Charmander","Basic", ["atk_type - Fire ", "Attacks - Ember, Scratch, Fire Punch, Tackle, Damage 4"], 60)
    print(Charmender)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

i have tried many solutions but it keeps looping could someone help with simple code. thank you!

Comment: It seems to me that you want to react to the `choice` variable, that is set by the user input. If so, you might benefit from having a look at the [documentation for pythons if/else-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements). You probably want something like: `if choice == "2":` followed by the action to take then.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant to do :

```py
import random

class Pokemon():
    def __init__(self,name,stage,atk_type,hp):
        self.name = name
        self.stage = stage
        self.atk_type = atk_type
        self.hp = hp

    def __str__(self):
                return(f"name: {self.name}\nstage: {self.stage}\natk_type: {self.atk_type}\nhp: {self.hp}\n")


def menu():
    count = 0
    while(count<2):
        print("Pick Your Pokemon:\n 1. Squirtle\n 2. Charizard\n 3. Exit")
        choice = input("Pick Your Pokemon! : ")
        
        Charizard = Pokemon("Charizard", "Stage 2 ", ["atk_type - Fire", "Attacks - Flamethrower, Ember, Fire Blast , Damage 12"], 120)
        
        Squirtle = Pokemon("Squirtle", "Basic", ["atk_type - Water", "Attacks - Bubble, Tackle, Water Pulse, AQUA Jet, Damage 3"], 60)
        
        if(choice=="1"):
            print(Squirtle)
            count += 1
        elif(choice=="2"):
            print(Charizard)
            count += 1
        elif(choice=="3"):
            break
        else:
            continue
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

Please tell me if this is what you needed.

Basically, you need to check what the user inputs using the "choice" variable and depending on what the variable is equal to, print the correct object.

Increment the count variable by 1 after each choice so that the loop stops after 2 choices.

---

**Explanation of the count variable:**

The first step is saying that count is equal to zero :
`count = 0`
Then, you put the main loop in a while loop with the condition that the loop will only start if count is inferior to count :
`while(count<2):`
So it starts once since count is equal to zero.

Then, whenever a user makes a valid choice, you say that count should increment. (meaning it should add one to itself) like so:`count += 1`

Therefore, when two choices have been made, the choice variable is equal to two and the loop stops.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: yh works perfectly fine you see how you added count what does that do, why did you use that am new and i want to know what it does in the program.